# Should a model contain an id?

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller, model

I'm writing a database driven java application containing models. I don't know where to place the id. Should this be in a model or another object.

```
public class model {
    int id;
    int data;
}
```

Also, how do I create the initial id value?

Comment: Looks fine. Before it is saved to the DB the ID is not set.

Comment: @juergend So I can just let the database generate the id?

Comment: If you have multiple entities, all mapped by, e.g., a `long` value, you can create an abstract super-class, containing the id.

Comment: @jax: Yes, the DB table column should be set to AUTO-INCREMENT. The DB sets the ID on insertion of the record. You grab that ID value from the DB and set it in the object

Comment: @jax well... what kind of framework are you using? [JPA, for example, has `@GeneratedValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) to mark properties generated by the database.

Comment: @Turing85 That would be possible, but do they actually do that?

Comment: @Turing85 I'm not using any framework at the moment. It is just a bare-bones database backed application.

Comment: @jax "*That would be possible, but do they actually do that?*" - You mean being mapped by the same key-type? We do not know, you should know that. But [it is a good idea to give each table a numeric primary key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66322).

Comment: @juergend Okay, thanks for clearing that up. Was just wondering if there were any best practices that are better.

Comment: @jax The best practice is *usually* to use JPA. Check tutorials for Spring Boot with JPA (even if you're not using Spring, they'll be up-to-date regarding best practices).

Comment: @chrylis I check out similar question and it was also suggested to use framework. I'm gonna go with Hibernate. The reason being that i'm not using any other framework currently, and don't feel the need to. I think adding Hibernate is sufficient. It will probably consist of JavaFx, MySql, and, now, Hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate is an implementation of JPA, and it is best to use the JPA interfaces when interacting with it. (Using Hibernate as your choice of JPA provider is a solid one.) If you're going as far as using a full database like MySQL or Postgres, then it's also worth considering using Spring Boot to manage your JavaFX application; it makes management of tasks like transactions and repositories (as well as configuring Hibernate) much simpler.

Comment: @chrylis Well, I want to start simple first. Later, if deemed necessary, I would consider using Spring Booot, but like I said, it isn't a monster of an app. I will keep your suggestions in mind, however. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm writing a database driven java application containing models.

If the model classes hold the database information, these classes are the best locations to store the id of the table/view/collection that they represent.
Generally you represent the id directly as a `int/long` for non composite keys while you generally want to represent composite keys with a specific class such as :

```
public class Model {
    ModelPk modelPk;
    int data;
    //getters
}

public class ModelPK {
    long idFoo;
    long idBar;
    //getters
}
```

> Also, how do I create the initial id value?

With relational DB, the auto-increment sequence is generally the way.
With NoSQL DB, atomic sequence is possible while that is not the standard way (not necessarily scalable and adapted to the exploded data model). Other ways allow to generate unique object identifiers with some constraints that may be acceptable according to the case (for example that is not necessarily a series of number but a mix of timestamps and other things).

**In any case you never want to generate the identifier yourself** because guaranteeing that it is consistent and unique among potentially multiple clients from multiple applications is critical.